# How do I split values into equal ranges in one column and sum the associated value of another column in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe named `Cust_Amount` which is as follows:

```
Age    Amount_Spent
25       20
43       15
32       27
37       10
45       17
29       10
```

I want to break it down into equal sized age groups and sum the amount spent for each age groups as given below:

```
Age_Group  Total_Amount
 20-30     30
 30-40     37
 40-50     32
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `cut` to group the 'Age' and get the `sum` of 'Amount_Spent' based on the grouping variable.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,.(Total_Amount = sum(Amount_Spent)) , 
       by = .(Age_Group = cut(Age, breaks = c(20, 30, 40, 50)))]
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Age_Group = cut(Age, breaks = c(20, 30, 40, 50))) %>%
    summarise(Total_Amount = sum(Amount_Spent))
#     Age_Group Total_Amount
#      <fctr>        <int>
#1   (20,30]           30
#2   (30,40]           37
#3   (40,50]           32
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I used the dplyr way and it worked fine. However, I am getting the result in a descending order of 'Total_Amount', which is not desired. How do I rearrange the output to ascending order of 'Age_Group' ?

Comment: @SourabhBanik Isn't that the same result as the expected output?  If you need it to be ascending, then `%>% arrange(Total_Amount)`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a base solution using `cut` and `aggregate`, and then using `setNames` to name the resulting columns:

```
mydf$Age_Group <- cut(mydf$Age, breaks = seq(20,50, by = 10))
with(mydf, setNames(aggregate(Amount_Spent ~ Age_Group, FUN = sum), 
                    c('Age_Group', 'Total_Spent')))

  Age_Group Total_Spent
1   (20,30]          30
2   (30,40]          37
3   (40,50]          32
```

We can take it a step further using `gsub` to match your desired output (note that I'm no regular expression expert):

```
mydf$Age_Group <- 
    gsub(pattern = ',',
     x = gsub(pattern = ']', 
     x = gsub(pattern = '(', x = mydf$Age_Group, replacement = '', fixed = T),
     replacement = '', fixed = T),
     replacement = ' - ', fixed = T)
with(mydf, setNames(aggregate(Amount_Spent ~ Age_Group, FUN = sum), 
                  c('Age_Group', 'Total_Spent')))

  Age_Group Total_Spent
1   20 - 30          30
2   30 - 40          37
3   40 - 50          32
```